# Trouble scraping data traversing multiple pages

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, http-post

I've written a script in python to get data from a webpage. The site displays it's content across 60 pages. My scraper can parse data from it's second page. When I try to change the page number in `payload` parameter or create a loop to get data from few of the pages, it instantly breaks. How can I rectify my script in the such a way so that it can fetch data from all of the pages, not only from the second page. Thanks in advance.

1. Link to reach the site with data: [Page_link](http://registers.centralbank.ie/(X(1)S(41jowa2ablrahdzqc45i1q55))/FundSearchResultsPage.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1&searchType=Name&registers=6%2c29%2c44%2c45&searchEntity=FundServiceProvider&searchText=)
2. Link to replace with the below script: [page_url](http://registers.centralbank.ie/(X(1)S(41jowa2ablrahdzqc45i1q55))/FundSearchResultsPage.aspx)

I suppose, the pagination number lies in here:

```
ctl00$cphRegistersMasterPage$gvwSearchResults$ctl18$ddlPages:1
```

Here is the full script (working only for page 2):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "Link to replace with the above url" ##Replace the number 2 links here

formdata = {
    'searchEntity':'FundServiceProvider',
    'searchType':'Name',
    'searchText':'',
    'registers':'6,29,44,45',
    'AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport':'1'
}
req = requests.get(url,params=formdata,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text,"lxml")

VIEWSTATE = soup.select("#__VIEWSTATE")[0]['value']
EVENTVALIDATION = soup.select("#__EVENTVALIDATION")[0]['value']

payload = {
    '__EVENTTARGET':'','__EVENTARGUMENT':'','__LASTFOCUS':'','__VIEWSTATE':VIEWSTATE,'__SCROLLPOSITIONX':'0','__SCROLLPOSITIONY':'541','__EVENTVALIDATION':EVENTVALIDATION,'ctl00$cphRegistersMasterPage$gvwSearchResults$ctl18$ddlPages':1,'ctl00$cphRegistersMasterPage$gvwSearchResults$ctl18$btnNext.x':'260','ctl00$cphRegistersMasterPage$gvwSearchResults$ctl18$btnNext.y':'11'
}

with requests.session() as session:
    session.headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"}
    response = session.post(req.url,data=payload)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
    tabd = soup.select(".searchresults")[0]
    for items in tabd.select("tr")[:-1]:
        data = ' '.join([item.text for item in items.select("th,td")])
        print(data)
```

Comment: so you are able to get the information from the second page, but not the rest right?

Comment: Yes it is @eLRuLL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove the last 2 fields of payload data :

```
payload = {
    '__EVENTTARGET':'',
    '__EVENTARGUMENT':'',
    '__LASTFOCUS':'',
    '__VIEWSTATE':VIEWSTATE,
    '__SCROLLPOSITIONX':'0',
    '__SCROLLPOSITIONY':'541',
    '__EVENTVALIDATION':EVENTVALIDATION,
    'ctl00$cphRegistersMasterPage$gvwSearchResults$ctl18$ddlPages':1
}
```

instead of

```
payload = {
    '__EVENTTARGET':'',
    '__EVENTARGUMENT':'',
    '__LASTFOCUS':'',
    '__VIEWSTATE':VIEWSTATE,
    '__SCROLLPOSITIONX':'0',
    '__SCROLLPOSITIONY':'541',
    '__EVENTVALIDATION':EVENTVALIDATION,
    'ctl00$cphRegistersMasterPage$gvwSearchResults$ctl18$ddlPages':1,
    'ctl00$cphRegistersMasterPage$gvwSearchResults$ctl18$btnNext.x':'260',
    'ctl00$cphRegistersMasterPage$gvwSearchResults$ctl18$btnNext.y':'11'
}
```

And then updating `ctl00$cphRegistersMasterPage$gvwSearchResults$ctl18$ddlPages` value will get the correct page data

Comment: You are my hero @Bertrand Martel. I owe you big time. I wish i could hit the upvote button million times. It was just awesome. Could you please give a oneliner explanation as to why the code worked when the two fields were taken out. Thankssssssssssssss again.

Comment: @Topto it seems these fields are only present when you click on the buttons (left & right) but not when you select the dropdown. If you used those field I guess (not tested) that you would need to parse the view state & event validation data for each request (and pass it to subsequent call). I assume the server kind of invalidates the "view" (composed of view state & validation) when you put the next or prev field whereas when you don't specify it, it considers the initial state each time. But that's only a guess